# Apache Solr with C++ Application

Tags: c++, solr, indexing, lucene

I have a builder C++ application. I need to know how to use Solr with my C++ Application.
Solr is written in Java and runs as a standalone full-text search server within a servlet container such as Apache Tomcat or Jetty. 
I need solr for indexing and search.
is there any way to use Solr with my C++ application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll interact with Solr through HTTP, so using libcurl or POCO to make the request and then parse the resulting XML or JSON is a possible (and easy) solution.

The only client I've seen mentioned is [SolrCPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/solrcpp/), although I don't think that is maintained or available in any decent form any longer (It's the only one mentioned on the [Integrating Solr](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr) list).

Comment: I don't know how to deploy Solr with my setup C++ application?

Comment: Solr is a stand alone server - it's not an integrated part of your C++ application. You might want to look into a C++ Lucene implementation in that case.

Comment: there is no implementaion for C++!

Comment: There is - but you'll use a Solr Client in C++. Solr works as a server that you talk through to an HTTP based API, so there is no need to have a c++ implementation of Solr.

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out the most easy solution through http.